# Linq query related to some properties

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new here so please be tolerant :)

I have query like this below:

```
ThesisListViewModel reviewModel = new ThesisListViewModel
            {
                ThesisModel = from the in thesisNavigatorRepository.Thesis
                              join tp1 in thesisNavigatorRepository.ThesisType1 on the.ThesisType1Id equals tp1.ThesisType1Id
                              join tp2 in thesisNavigatorRepository.ThesisType2 on the.ThesisType2Id equals tp2.ThesisType2Id
                              select  new ThesisModel
                              {
                                  Thesis_ThesisId = the.ThesisId,
                                  Thesis_Subject = the.Subject,
                                  Thesis_ShortDescription = the.ShortDescription,
                                  ThesisType1_Description = tp1.Description,
                                  ThesisType2_Description = tp2.Description,
                                  Thesis_URL = the.URL,
                                  Thesis_ThesisLocalization = the.ThesisLocalization,

                                  AuthorModel = from per in thesisNavigatorRepository.Person
                                                join uod in thesisNavigatorRepository.UnitOfDepartment on per.UODId equals uod.UODId
                                                join dep in thesisNavigatorRepository.Department on uod.DepartmentId equals dep.DepartmentId
                                                join ptt in thesisNavigatorRepository.PersonToThesis on per.PersonId equals ptt.PersonId
                                                join prr in thesisNavigatorRepository.PersonRole on ptt.PersonRoleId equals prr.PersonRoleId
                                                where ptt.ThesisId == the.ThesisId && ptt.PersonRoleId == 1
                                                select new AuthorModel
                                                {
                                                    Person_FistName = per.FirstName,
                                                    Person_LastName = per.LastName,
                                                    UnitOfDepartment_ShortName = uod.ShortName,
                                                    UnitOfDepartment_LongName = uod.LongName,
                                                    Department_ShortName = dep.ShortName,
                                                    Department_LongName = dep.LongName,
                                                },

                                  StaffModel = from per in thesisNavigatorRepository.Person
                                               join uod in thesisNavigatorRepository.UnitOfDepartment on per.UODId equals uod.UODId
                                               join dep in thesisNavigatorRepository.Department on uod.DepartmentId equals dep.DepartmentId
                                               join ptt in thesisNavigatorRepository.PersonToThesis on per.PersonId equals ptt.PersonId
                                               join prr in thesisNavigatorRepository.PersonRole on ptt.PersonRoleId equals prr.PersonRoleId
                                               where ptt.ThesisId == the.ThesisId && ptt.PersonRoleId != 1
                                               select new StaffModel
                                               {
                                                   Person_FistName = per.FirstName,
                                                   Person_LastName = per.LastName,
                                                   Person_Title = per.Title,
                                                   UnitOfDepartment_ShortName = uod.ShortName,
                                                   UnitOfDepartment_LongName = uod.LongName,
                                                   Department_ShortName = dep.ShortName,
                                                   Department_LongName = dep.LongName,
                                               },
                              },

                ThesisType1Model = thesisNavigatorRepository.ThesisType1,
                ThesisType2Model = thesisNavigatorRepository.ThesisType2,
                PersonModel = thesisNavigatorRepository.Person,
                PersonRoleModel = thesisNavigatorRepository.PersonRole,
                UnitOfDepartmentModel = thesisNavigatorRepository.UnitOfDepartment,
                DepartmentModel = thesisNavigatorRepository.Department
            };
            return PartialView(reviewModel);
```

And I would like to make it dependent on some properties which I am passing to an action method.

The condition which I need is below (simple version):

```
if(property1 == null or property2 == null) -> query for ThesisModel without where clause

elseif(property1 == null) ThesisModel where tp2.Description like property2

elseif(property2 == null) ThesisModel where tp1.Description like property1

else ThesisModel where tp1.Description like property1 and tp2.Description like property2
```

I am stuck. I can of course make different queries for each condition but I hope that exist easiest way.

Could you please help?

P.S.
My english is poor so sorry if I made some mistakes.

EDIT:

I had tried with your ideas but I stil cannot use it in my project.
I am passing data to my controler from view using below properties:

```
    public string SearchByType1 { get; set; }
    public string SearchByType2 { get; set; }
    public string SearchByPerson { get; set; }
    public string SearchByPersonRole { get; set; }
    public string SearchByUOD { get; set; }
    public string SearchByDepartment { get; set; }
```

Each property is related to other table as you can see in my controler. Using PredicateBuilder looks easy only when my conditions are related to one property in one table. Currently for two properties I have such conditions:

```
where
                              (
                              string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.SearchByType1) 
                              && 
                              string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.SearchByType2)
                              )
                              ||
                              (
                              string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.SearchByType1) 
                              && 
                              SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)tp2.ThesisType2Id).Trim().Equals(model.SearchByType2)
                              )
                              ||
                              (
                              string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.SearchByType2) 
                              && 
                              SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)tp1.ThesisType1Id).Trim().Equals(model.SearchByType1)
                              )
                              ||
                              (
                              SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)tp1.ThesisType1Id).Trim().Equals(model.SearchByType1) 
                              && 
                              SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)tp2.ThesisType2Id).Trim().Equals(model.SearchByType2)
                              )
```

It works but looks terrible and I have no ideas further. Could you please elaborete your ideas and help?

Just for information I am using SqlFunctions.StringConvert because of parameters coming from (they are from dropdownlist - id as string).

Answer (score 0):

Declare each condition as a Func and then pass it to the query. Something along the lines of:

```
Func<string, bool> predicate;

if (prop1 == null && prop2 == null)
    predicate = (s1, s2) => true;
else if (prop1 == null)
    predicate = (s1, s2) => prop2 == s2;
else if (prop2 == null)
    predicate = (s1, s2) => prop1 == s1;
else
    predicate = (s1, s2) => prop1 == s1 && prop2 == s2;

var model = thesisNavigatorRepository.Thesis.Where(t => predicate(t.Description1, t.Description2));
```

Comment: Your `else if` statement will never get executed because it would also be true for your `if` statement

Comment: never mind you fixed it before I finished my comment

Comment: Yeah, I copied the logic in the question and then realised the first OR should probably be an AND.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `PredicateBuilder` class

Just add the Linqkit dll to your project.
this is the Linqkit Link:http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx